# Oscillator with non-linear damping - question re a specific approach

Tags: oscillators, differential-equations, non-linear-systems

The following paper

https://core.ac.uk/reader/82037870

**Oscillators with nonlinear elastic and damping forces**

L.Cveticanin

studies the general problem

$$ \ddot{x} + 2 b_k \, \dot{x} \, |\dot{x}|^k + \omega^2 x = 0 $$

The author introduces slow degrees of freedoms and integrates out (averages over) the fast ones, using the ansatz (17)

$$ x(t) = A(t) \, \sin(\omega t + \theta) $$

My question is about the slow amplitude $A(t)$.

Using $k=2$ and (55) one finds a solution

$$ A(t) = \frac{A_0}{1 + A_0 \xi t} $$

$$ A_0 = A(0) $$

This agrees with a straight forward approach using Krylov–Bogoliubov averaging.

**First question**: Is there any reason why the author restricts this solution to $k < 1$? I used a different approach for $k=2$ and found exactly the same expression.

Then the author claims that "*in Eq (55), the first two terms represent the series expansion of an exponential function and Eq.(55) can be rewritten as*"

$$ A(t) = A_0 \exp\left(- A_0 \xi t\right) $$

**Second question**: Is there any further justification for this in this 'improvement'?

I have doubts.

For (55) one can immediately show that

$$ A(t) = \frac{A_0}{1 + A_0 \xi t} \stackrel{!}{=} \frac{A_1 }{1 + A_1 \xi (t-t_1)} $$

$$ A_1 = A(t_1) = \frac{A_0 }{1 + A_0 \xi t_1} $$

which means that one shifts the initial condition from $t_0=0$ to some $t_1$.

However, this fails for the exponential approach

$$ A(t) = A_0 \exp\left(- A_0 \xi t\right) \stackrel{!}{=} A_1 \exp\left(- A_1 \xi (t-t_1)\right) $$

$$ A_1 = A(t_1) = A_0 \exp\left(- A_0 \xi t_1\right) $$

Comment: It might be hard to figure out what to do without the pesky RHS of the first equation block (I presume $=0$ is missing, but it could be some other constant).

Comment: Sorry, silly mistake on my part. Of course = 0. I corrected it.